# Fetching order details but items and extension_attributes array are empty

Tags: magento2, sales-order

```
public function execute()
{
    $order=$this->orderFactory->load(1); 
    $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    //echo $item->getProductId();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($item->getData());
    echo "</pre>";
    }
    exit();
  return $resultPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't use service contact class `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`

You have using factory `$order=$this->orderFactory->load(1);`that why you  donot getting extension attribute value.

You have to use the Repository class.

`$order=$this->OrderRepository->get(1);`

Comment: thanks, I have tried that one too, even though that still getting empty both